# Which chart/plotting plugin is quicker than ploty?

Tags: plotly

I am implementing a WebPage that includes a ChartView. In this chart, many traces with large data amount will be shown.

It should be "much" quicker than plotly. Unfortunatally I dont really know others plugins for that purpose. Thease that I have found are slower.

Do you have any purposes? The language does not matter.

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want quicker there are these:
- C3.js
- Victory
- Chart.js

Then it also depends on your case

C3 can be used with any framework
Victory is convenient only for react apps
Chart is most active project but no support for time series
So, these are quicker but for choosing the library consider these arguments